# How to read file in R with column names having brackets?

Tags: r, file, brackets

I have one input file.

cat file

```
      IstCol (ABC) IInd COl (DEF) 
      34           45 
      32           45

      > input<-read.table("file",sep="\t",header=TRUE)
      > input
      IstCol..ABC..IInd.COl..DEF.
      1            34           45 
      2             32           45
```

But it does not recognise brackets. What changes need to be made to recognize it?

Comment: NO reply...... Pls help .... as i m in great need

Comment: Some one has replied answer on R forum so thought to share his reply.dat1<- read.table(text="
      IstCol (ABC), IInd COl (DEF)      
        34,45
      32,45
",sep=",",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE)

Comment: Perhaps you can turn your findings into an answer and accept.

Answer (score 2):

`read.table` is by default checking if column names are valid variable names and if they are unique, you can turn it off by setting `check.names = F` :

```
input <- read.table("file", sep="\t", header=T, check.names=F)
```

Column names matter if you would like to use `$` operator to call the variables. Description from manual :

```
check.names: logical.  If 'TRUE' then the names of the variables in the
          data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically
          valid variable names.  If necessary they are adjusted (by
          'make.names') so that they are, and also to ensure that there
          are no duplicates.
```